# Why its easier to tie things with multiple loops to the thread for hanging from a pivot?

Tags: friction, everyday-life

We often see that hanging a object by looping a thread around a pivot many times will make the thread to not fall off, but when looped less than critical needed the object falls off, **is the friction here playing a big role?**
Is it that more frictional force is supporting the object to be hanging , if its lesser than a special value it can slide off and object will drop?

Comment: The tension will only get less on the other side of the thread, over the pivot.

Comment: Why @Felicia  .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Friction is the force keeping the object from falling, but friction and tension play a reciprocally reinforcing role.

In reality tension will vary continuously within a loop, and I'm not sure how the calculus falls out, but we can create a toy model using a simple geometric progression to illustrate.

Suppose you have $n$ loops and the string is under tension $T_1$ in the first loop, $T_2$ in the second loop, and so on.

The first loop has a friction force proportional to the normal force between the loop and the string, which is proportional to the tension, $F_1 = aT_1$ for some constant $a$.

The second loop is under tension equal to the friction force applied by the first loop, plus the initial tension $T_2 = F_1 = (a+1)T_1$. Its friction force is proportional to the normal force between the loop and the string, which is proportional to the tension, $F_2 = (a(a+1)) T_1$. This in turn creates a tension force for the third loop $T_3 = (a^2+a+1)T_1$, and so on.

Extrapolating, $F_n \approx (a+1)^n T_1 \gg T_1$.

You can do this experiment at home. Select a length of fine sturdy string, perhaps a length of dental floss. Tie a small weight of which you have several to supply the initial tension on the string, for instance, a pen. Tie the other end to a paper cup. Loop the string once around a sturdy pivot, for instance, a broom handle. See how much water you can lift before the string starts to slide. Add a second loop, taking care not to cross the string, and try again. Repeat for 3 loops, 4 loops, and so on. Repeat the whole experiment with 2 pens, 3 pens, and 4 pens.

I predict your data for supported quantity of water will vary roughly exponentially with number of loops, and vary roughly linearly with number of weights (e.g. pens).

Comment: It can be argued by capstan equation too right Sir ? T'= Te^utheta and so on..?